# Python, Django: getting full path from file

Tags: python, django, file, input, path

Good evening,

I'm trying to select a file ("example.csv") via a *input* inside my template:

**main.html**

```
...
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Choose</button>
</form>
...
```

After selecting and hitting the button I want to achieve the full path plus the name of the file itself as a string!

**views.py**

```
...
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myFile']:
    myFile = request.FILES['myFile']
    file_path = # getting the full file path
...
```

**For example:**

- data_name = 'example.csv'
- file_path = 'C:\Users\John Doe\Files'

So the string should look something like this: **'C:\Users\John Doe\Files\example.csv'**

I tried it with *os.path*, but this doesn't seem to work or I'm doing something wrong here!?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: what exactly is file_path here where does it come from?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to get the user's local path of the file, the browser doesn't give such information. Usually the information you get is the Size, Type, Filename.

Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31691901/11132419), [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40284712/11132419) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993564/11132419)