# Openpyxl Django

Tags: django, excel, openpyxl

Trying to automate modifying an Ecxel file using openpyxl lib and below code works:

```
def modify_excel_view(request):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\my_dir\\filename.xlsx')
    sh1 = wb['Sheet1']
    row = sh1.max_row
    column = sh1.max_column
    for i in range(2, row + 1):
        # ...some_code...
    wb.save('C:\\my_dir\\new_filename.xlsx')
    return render(request, 'my_app/convert.html', {'wb': wb})
```

1. But how to implement a similar method without static (hardcoding) path to file and a filename? Like choosing xlsx file from modal window?
2. Saving modified copy on a desktop by default? (Maybe like 'ReportLab library': response.write(pdf)=>return response. And it saving on the desktop by default.)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can send the file path and name as POST parameters and extract them in the views.py function using `request.POST.get('file_path')`.
2. Just add a line to save the copy to the desktop before returning.

Comment: Thanks @Bhavya Peshavaria 1) Well, ok. Under `'file_path'` you mean `'C:\\my_dir\\filename.xlsx'`? And what about filename? It may change. 2) The path to desktop on each computer has different way I mean on Alex PC it will be `C:\Users\Alex\Desktop` on John's PC `C:\Users\John\Desktop` and so on but I need universal solution.

Comment: For system-dependent variables, use environment variables in projects. you can access them using os.env.get("filepath")

Comment: Thanks! Second question is clear. Which is not clear to me is how to send `'file_path'` as POST parameter? Could give me example of code pls? Thanks

Comment: I found that there is impossible to get user's path - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65532871/15249596 from browser. Any suggestions pls?

Comment: Okay got it, but why do you need the user's file location path?

Comment: for this part of code `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\my_dir\\filename.xlsx')` My app do not use Models and DB, all excel modify is on 'fly'

Comment: In that case, the best you can do is take the path from the user or use the username named folders.